# Does interface belong to ad hoc polymorphism (i.e. overloading) or subtype polymorphism?

Tags: oop, haskell, polymorphism, subtyping, adhoc-polymorphism

https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism says

> **Ad-hoc polymorphism** refers to when a value is able to adopt any one of several types because it, or a value it uses, has been given a separate definition for each of those types. For example, the + operator essentially does something entirely different when applied to floating-point values as compared to when applied to integers – in Python it can even be applied to strings as well. Most languages support at least some ad-hoc polymorphism, but in languages like C it is restricted to only built-in functions and types. Other languages like C++ allow programmers to provide their own **overloading**, supplying multiple definitions of a single function, to be disambiguated by the types of the arguments. In Haskell, this is achieved via the system of **type classes** and class instances.
>
> Despite the similarity of the name, Haskell's **type classes** are quite
> different from the classes of most object-oriented languages. They
> have more in common with **interfaces**, in that they specify a series of
> methods or values by their type signature, to be implemented by an
> instance declaration.

Does it mean that type classes is a way to achieve overloading i.e. ad hoc polymorphism?

What kind of polymorphism does interface in OO languages (e.g. Java, C#) belong to, ad hoc polymorphism (i.e. overloading) or subtype polymorphism?

- Since type class is similar to interface, is interface a way to achieve overloading i.e. ad hoc polymorphism, just as type class is?
- Is interface   similar to base class, so is interface a way to achieve subtype polymorphism, just as class inheritance is?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Haskell type classes are a way to achieve ad-hoc polymorphism. Interfaces in C# or Java implement subtype polymorphism: an object that implements an interface is a subtype of that interface.

Comment: Subtyping is simply not in Haskell. This is because subtyping is not compatible with Hindley-Milner type inference. Subtyping is a purely OO concept.

Comment: @AJFarmar rank-2 types with typeclass constraints can be used to achieve, essentially, subtyping. This isn't usually a very practical thing to do, but it can be very powerful, with the most prominent example being the [lens hierarchy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Comment: @AJFarmar, relatedly/more generally, subsumption can be seen as an extremely restricted form of subtyping. `(forall a. a -> a) ≤ (Int -> Int)`.

Comment: @AJF OCaml has successfully integrated subtyping into its ML-base type system.

Answer (score 3):

**Types** has not type hierarchy, but **Typeclasses** has.

I wouldn't think about type classes as class inheritance, because you don't have the parent structure, you just have the signature. They may be seen as the classic interfaces of OOP languages, kind of...

But as the text you quoted says:

> For example, the `(+)` operator essentially does something entirely different when applied to floating-point values as compared to when applied to integers

Something so simple as `(+)` function, with types are not so.

You have here a `TypeClass` hierarchy of `Num` to respect. For example

```
plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a
plus x y = x + y
```

and there you have (I can count) four direct subtypes `Integral` (implemented by `Int` and `Integral`) and `Fractional` (implemented by `Float` and `Double`). `Integral` and `Fractional` typeclasses are subtypes of `Num` typeclass.

so, look at this function type signatures:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a

(div) :: Integral a => a -> a -> a

(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

each one of those has it's own implementation, and restricts the data type you can use in those type hierarchies of subtypes and supertypes, always talking about the `Typeclass` and not **the type itself**.

About the relation with OOP:

In Java by example, the Types and The classes are veeeeeeery different things. Look:

```
List<String> xs = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ys = new LinkedList<>();
xs.add("Haskell");
ys.add("Forever");
```

The type there, is `List`, but the behavior of those lists is given by the **Class** (ArrayList or LinkedList).
And even more, you can do:

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add("something);
```

Is valid, the type and the class are the same.

On the other hand, in Haskell is not like that, the `(+)` method behavior is given by the **implementation of the type according to its typeclass**.

There is an example of a classic useful `Typeclass` hierarchy in Haskell:

[image: Typeclass Hierarchy:]

Comment: Types in Haskell are not subtypes of type classes (e.g. Int is not a subtype of Integral) because type classes are not types (e.g. Integral is not a type). There is no type hierarchy. There is a type class hierarchy.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you so much for helping me improve my answer, I've taken your advice and edited the question, I really want a feedback from you, to know if it needs to be improved or if it is fine now, thanks os much for the time